# Replace string with result of command

Tags: bash, python-3.x, replace, awk, sed

I have data in `zdt` format (like [this](http://pastebin.com/fRemVPyT)), where I want to perform [this python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200349/convert-numbered-pinyin-to-pinyin-with-tone-marks) only on the third column (the pinyin one). I have tried to do this with `sed` and `awk` but I have not had any success due to my limited knowledge of these tools. Ideally, I want to feed the column’s contents to the python script and then have the source replaced with the yield of the script.

This is roughly what I envision but the call is not executed, not even when in quotes.

```
s/([a-z]+[1,2,3,4]?)(?=.*\t)/decode_pinyin(\1)/g
```

I am not too strict of the tools (`sed`, `awk`, python, …) used, I just want a shell script for batch processing of a number of files. It would be best if the original spaces are preserved.

Comment: did you want to store only the third column in a txt file for later processing?

Comment: You should use python for the whole solution

Comment: @AvinashRaj No I want to keep the original content so that the first colum for example becomes `入鄉隨俗    入乡随俗    rùxiāng suísú       /When in Rome, do as the Romans/`

Comment: `sed` can't call functions when it does substitution. But several scripting languages can do it: Perl has the `e` modifier, PHP has `preg_replace_callback()`, Javascript allows the replacement in `RegExp::replace` to be a function, and I'll bet Python has something similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call functions from re.sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944978/call-functions-from-re-sub)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{printf "decode_pinyin(\"%s\")\n", $3}' file
```

This outputs:

```
decode_pinyin("ru4xiang1 sui2su2")
decode_pinyin("ru4")
decode_pinyin("xiang1")
decode_pinyin("sui2")
decode_pinyin("su2")
```